# Reshaping long vector

Tags: matrix

I have a very long matrix `spectrum={{k1,w1},{k2,w2}......{kn, wn}}`. The frequency component "w" may randomly be repeated along the list. I want to reorganize the spectrum in such a way that all k values corresponding to the same w are stored in sublist. Something like this, `newspectrum={{{k1,k5,k8,k13},w1}, {....., w2}, {....,w3}.....}`. Notice that `k1`, `k5`, `k8`, `k13` are all paired with the same `w` value in the "spectrum" list. How can I reshape the list according to the new form.

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = {#[[All, 1]], #[[1, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[#, Last] &;
```

Example:

```
ks = Symbol["k" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[10];
ws = Symbol["w" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[5];
SeedRandom[1]
t = RandomChoice[Tuples[{ks, ws}], 10]
```

> {{k5, w1}, {k1, w2}, {k10, w4}, {k1, w3}, {k2, w2}, {k1, w4}, {k4, 
>         w2}, {k6, w4}, {k7, w4}, {k7, w2}}

```
f @ t
```

> {{{k5}, w1}, {{k1, k2, k4, k7}, w2}, {{k10, k1, k6, k7}, w4}, {{k1}, 
>         w3}}

Comment: Thanks kglr and sorry for not writing above that the list spectrum is numeric. Does your solution work for numerical list as well?

Comment: @qahtah, it should work for numeric lists too; try `f @spectrum`.